# Cómo hacer una consulta de múltiples tablas

Tags: php, html, mysql

de nuevo estoy un poco estancado. quiero hacer una consulta con información de 3 tablas

Tabla 1 Ticket

```
+------------+-------------+----------------+-------+-----------+
| id_ticket  | Title       | created_at     | cat_id| update_at |
+------------+-------------+----------------+-------+-----------+
|          1 |Sta Clara    | 15:44:48       | 1     | 15:58:02  |
|          2 |Ecatepec     | 12:51:21       | 2     | 13:05:03  |
|          3 |Veracruz     | 10:22:30       | 1     | 11:50:49  |
+------------+-------------+----------------+-------+-----------+
```

Tabla 2 Category

```
+------------+-------------+
| cat_id     | name        |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |F09          |
|          2 |K18          |
|          3 |2DM34-09     |
+------------+-------------+
```

Tabla 3 Historico

```
+------------+-------------+----------------+-------+
| id         | ubicacion   | update_at      | cat_id|
+------------+-------------+----------------+-------+
|          1 |Sta Clara    | 15:44:48       | 1     |
|          2 |Ecatepec     | 12:51:2        | 2     |
|          3 |Veracruz     | 10:22:3        | 1     |
+------------+-------------+----------------+-------+
```

Cómo pueden ver las tablas están relacionas entre ellas, en la tabla 1 se guarda el cat_id de la tabla 2 para poder recuperar el nombre del item y en la tabla 3 se tiene también el cat_id de la tabla 2 con el mismo propósito y también se tiene el mismo update_at de la Tabla 1

Deseo que mi consulta me muestre toda la información de esas 3 tablas a partir del cat_id, yo intenté la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT ticket.title, ticket.created_at, ticket.updated_at, category.name, 
       historico.ultimaubicacion 
FROM ticket, category, historico 
WHERE category.id = 2 AND category.id = historico.category_id 
ORDER BY updated_at ASC
```

Obviamente sé que está mal hecha mi consulta porque me arroja todos los datos repetidos.

Leí un poco acerca de JOIN e INNER JOIN y que posiblemente era la manera correcta de resolver mi problema, pero no he podido entender como aplicarlo en mi caso particular.

**RESUELTO**

Gracias a la colaboración de la comunidad y jugando un poco este es el método para hacer la consulta de las 3 columnas obteniendo todos los datos necesarios de las 3 tablas

`SELECT ticket.title, ticket.created_at, ticket.updated_at, category.name, historico.ultimaubicacion 
FROM ticket, category, historico 
WHERE
ticket.ultimaubicacion = historico.ultimaubicacion AND
ticket.cat_id = cat.id`

Comment: Primero que nada, tienes creadas llaves foráneas entre tus tablas, o solo le pusiste el mismo nombre a la columna y le pusiste el numero que querías.

Comment: Es fácil, tienes que aprender a usar INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN O RIGHT JOIN puedes saber más aqui: [https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/diferencias-entre-join-left-join-y-right-join.html](http://%20https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/diferencias-entre-join-left-join-y-right-join.html)

Comment: Las claves foráneas están hechas, en este caso cat_id es una de ellas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La informacion de las 3 tablas la obtendrias asi:

```
SELECT ticket.title, ticket.created_at, ticket.updated_at, category.name, 
       historico.ubicacion, historico.updated_at as 'h_updated_at'
FROM ticket, category, historico 
WHERE
    category.cat_id = 2 AND
    category.cat_id = historico.cat_id AND
    category.cat_id = ticket.cat_id
```

En este caso, no es totalmente necesario usar un JOIN o INNER JOIN, tan solo para que tu consulta sea legible para otro programador.

Comment: Gracias, creo que fue mas sencillo hacer de este modo la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

RESUELTO

Gracias a la colaboración de la comunidad y jugando un poco este es el método para hacer la consulta de las 3 columnas obteniendo todos los datos necesarios de las 3 tablas

`SELECT ticket.title, ticket.created_at, ticket.updated_at, category.name, historico.ultimaubicacion 
FROM ticket, category, historico 
WHERE
ticket.ultimaubicacion = historico.ultimaubicacion AND
ticket.cat_id = cat.id`

Comment: Entonces considera marcar tu respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Cómo hago eso? soy nuevo en la comunidad, disculpa